# javascript if else change css proberty

Tags: javascript, css

I can't find out what's wrong wit this simple code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
setInterval(function ranpic1(){
  
    {
   var pic-a = 0;
      pic-a = Math.random();
      pic-a *= 9; 
   pic-a = Math.ceil(pic-a);

    }


if (pic-a < 3.3) {document.getElementsByClassName("item-101").style.backgroundImage="url(/lcm-1.png)";}
else if (pic-a > 6.6) {document.getElementsByClassName("item-101").style.backgroundImage="url(/lcm-1b.png)";}
else {document.getElementsByClassName("item-101").style.backgroundImage="url(/lcm-1a.png)";}

},1000);
```

do you have an idea?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! "Here's my code, fix it" is not the way to go around here. Try reading up a bit : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This should help you: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/ .

Comment: insert some `console.log()` into your code a bunch so you can see how far your code gets before it makes an error. Also, check the console period before doing even that to see what it says.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have dashes in variable names.